# Android: delegate touch event to underlaying view

Tags: android, events, touch

I have the following hierarchy: `Activity` -> `PopupWindow` -> `CustomView`

My the `PopupWindow` itself is a square, but transparent, so you can see the Activity sitting in the background. The `CustomView` is a circle embedded inside the PopupWindow.
[image]

What I have achieved so far is

1. User clicks on green circle and I invoke "some stuff"
2. User clicks outside of the `PopupWindow` and the touch event gets dispatched to the Activity.

The missing part is now, to dispatch any touch event that happens inside the `PopupWindow` but outside the `CustomView` (circle) to the Activity.

I already know how to sense when the touch is outside of my circle. I just have problems delegating it to the Activity.

In my `CustomView` I have the following in `onTouch`

```
if (radiusTouch > maxRadius) {
    return false;
}
```

In my `PopupWindow` I already setup the following, but it gets never called:

```
popup.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "PopupWindow :: onTouch()");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Anything else I have to do to delegate the touch event all the way to the Activity?

Comment: how did you create that mockup?  it's pretty slick

Comment: How did you manage to dispatch the click events to the views below the PopUpWindow?

Comment: Mocups have been done by balsamic mockups http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949673/android-click-through-popupwindow

Answer (score 13):

Consider the FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL:

```
/** Window flag: Even when this window is focusable (its
  * {@link #FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE is not set), allow any pointer events
  * outside of the window to be sent to the windows behind it.  Otherwise
  * it will consume all pointer events itself, regardless of whether they
  * are inside of the window. */
public static final int FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL    = 0x00000020;
```

You can use this code to upate the window flags *after* the popup window was shown.

```
FrameLayout popupContainer = (FrameLayout)contentView.getParent();
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = (WindowManager.LayoutParams)popupContainer.getLayoutParams();
p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.updateViewLayout(popupContainer, p);
```

Comment: Ok. It works. I can touch on both views inside `popupWindow` and activity's views. Just `updateViewLayout(contentView, p)` , no `contentView.getParent()`

Answer (score 3):

Try setting these on your PopupWindow instance:

`window.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());`

`window.setOutsideTouchable(true);`

and

`window.setTouchable(true);`

This is just a suggestion... I haven't tested it.
Let me know if it works.

[Note: This is for the onTouch() to get called on touch events..]

Answer (score 0):

It's too bad that the PopupWindow is not a subclass of ViewGroup or even View.  Then you could override dispatchTouchEvent.  Can you modify your custom view to know about the PopupWindow and call dismiss() on it when there is a click outside the circle?