# The touched control does not gain focus, when I touch outside of the PopupWindow

Tags: android, focus, popupwindow

When I touch a control outside of the PopupWindow, the popup dismissed, but the touched control does not get focus.

**Q:** What can be done, to make sure the clicked control get focus?

I tried setOutsideTouchable with no luck, it looks like this method is for some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

[Android: delegate touch event to underlaying view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832893/android-delegate-touch-event-to-underlaying-view/4658231#4658231)