# Android Click Through PopupWindow

Tags: android, onclicklistener, z-order

I have created a class that extends popupwindow. its constructor looks something like the following

```
super(builder.context.get());

this.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
setFocusable(true);
setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
setTouchInterceptor(onTouchListener);
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(builder.context.get());
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) builder.context.get().getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View overlayBase = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_view_items, null, false);
frameLayout.addView(builder.backgroundView);
frameLayout.addView(overlayBase);
setContentView(frameLayout);
```

the onTouchListener looks like the following:

```
private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        Log.d(TAG, "Received");

        if (Math.pow(x - coordinates[0], 2) + Math.pow((y - coordinates[1]), 2) < Math.pow(radius, 2)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "bubbled through");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

to actually display the popupwindow, I call `SomePopupWindow.showAtLocation(SomeActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);`

Visually represented, here is the product in question

[image: blah]

The touchListener is responding, but the input does not get sent to the underlying activity OR the popupwindow? (the button is unresponsive, where as if i were to remove the ontouchlistener, the button works fine).

**update**
setting the touch listener to the frameLayout (i.e. content view of popupwindow in this case) instead of the popupwindow itself allows me to click on the buttons defined in the popup.  still looking for way to delegate the touch event to the underlying activity/view

**SOLUTION**

Register a touch interceptor for the Popupwindow.  If you want the activity to handle it, assuming you have a reference to the activity, call `someActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(someMotionEventPassedIntoTheTouchIntercepter);`, if you want the popupwindow to handle the touch even, call `someView.dispatchTouchEvent(theMotionEventPassedToTouchInterceptor)` to the popupwindow's **content view**, as set in the popupwindows `setContentView(someView)` method.

My method specifically looked like the following

```
private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (Math.pow(x - coordinates[0], 2) + Math.pow((y - coordinates[1]), 2) < Math.pow(
                radius, 2)) {
            activity.get().dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
        frameLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify whether "bubbled through" is actually being logged on the clicks you expect to fall through the popup?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion.  the ontouchlistener is being called, and the Log output follows accordingly depending on where I touch (i.e., "bubbled through" when i touch in the circle region)

Comment: Not sure then. If you need a hack solution, you can check if the touch is in the xy coordinates of the button and do a performClick(). Or maybe pass the touch explicitly to the onTouch of the Activity / View containing the button.  Hopefully someone can give u a better answer though.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Do you think it would be better to implement this idea through a different view container? dialog? dialogfragment? any experience with bubbling clicks through views to anchored activities?

Comment: I have updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Register a touch interceptor for the Popupwindow.  If you want the activity to handle it, assuming you have a reference to the activity, call `someActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(someMotionEventPassedIntoTheTouchIntercepter);`, if you want the popupwindow to handle the touch even, call `someView.dispatchTouchEvent(theMotionEventPassedToTouchInterceptor)` to the popupwindow's **content view**, as set in the popupwindows `setContentView(someView)` method.

My method specifically looked like the following

```
private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (Math.pow(x - coordinates[0], 2) + Math.pow((y - coordinates[1]), 2) < Math.pow(
                radius, 2)) {
            activity.get().dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
        frameLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello? `theMotionEventPassedToTouchInterceptor` You can tell more detail how to do this?

Comment: see how one of the parameters passed to the `onTouchListener` is of type `MotionEvent`?  if you have a reference to the underlying activity, pass it that touch event by calling yourActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent) (and then rrturn false!)

Comment: This right here, gave me a solution after 3 days of being stuck. You are the man !

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestPopupActivity extends Activity {

//The "x" and "y" position of the "Show Button" on screen.
Point p;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
   btn_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {

       //Open popup window
       if (p != null)
       showPopup(TestPopupActivity.this, p);
     }
   });
}

// Get the x and y position after the button is draw on screen
// (It's important to note that we can't get the position in the onCreate(),
// because at that stage most probably the view isn't drawn yet, so it will return (0, 0))
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

   int[] location = new int[2];
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);

   // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
   // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
   button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

   //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
   p = new Point();
   p.x = location[0];
   p.y = location[1];
}

// The method that displays the popup.
private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
   int popupWidth = 200;
   int popupHeight = 150;

   // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
   LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

   // Creating the PopupWindow
   final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
   popup.setContentView(layout);
   popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
   popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
   popup.setFocusable(true);

   // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
   int OFFSET_X = 30;
   int OFFSET_Y = 30;

   // Clear the default translucent background
   popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

   // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
   popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

   // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when clicked.
   Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
   close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       popup.dismiss();
     }
   });
}
}
```

try this code may be it help you . .. . .
or may be this link will help u more ..
http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285

Comment: Umm thanks? I had no issue inflating the popupwindow.  the problem is im not able to forward touch events to the view the popupwindow is anchored to.  As far as I can see, this implementation is not within the code snippet you have provided

Comment: Rperryng...is it necessary to be rude? "Umm thanks?" is inappropriate given that Hitesh is trying to help while interpreting your question.