# Android dispatch touch event to main activity when dialog is showing

Tags: android, android-activity, ontouchlistener, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment`, it's `onCreateDialog()` looks something like

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(parentView);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));

parentView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
return dialog;
```

The onTouchListener looks something like

```
private OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int[] coordinates = bundle.getIntArray(COORDINATES);
        int radius = bundle.getInt(RADIUS);

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        Log.d(TAG, "called touch");

        if (Math.pow(x - coordinates[0], 2) + Math.pow((y - coordinates[1]), 2) < Math.pow(
                radius, 2)) {
            getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "bubbled");
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

I would like the touch events that are in a particular region (see circle in pic below) to be handled by the activity instead, so that the button from the activity is clicked.  Otherwise, I want the dialog to handle the touch event.

[image: picture]

For the record, YES, the Log statement "`bubbled`" IS being called, so clearly the `getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(event)` method isn't working as intended.

I have noticed that sometime even the `onTouchEvent()` method from the activity is called, yet the button still doesn't respond, what gives?

Comment: Hey have you found solution to this  ?

Comment: Hey @Ramesh , I can't quite remember how I solved it as this was a couple years ago, but it seems i opted to use a popupwindow instead of a dialogue.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21969806/3194316

Comment: Hey I tried the above link but didnt work for me.  My issue was that I had this dialog on top of keyboard (Emoji's dialog fragment) and I wanted to hide it through fragment transaction and keep dialog open and transparent so that keyboard is visible and  send events through dialog to keyboard. I made a workaround by setting height of dialog to 0 when it is not needed. Thanks for the reply. Keeping this so that in case somebody faces this issue in my scenario :)